# How to properly use parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to properly use the below syntax. To access form method of top parent tag

I want to do something like this

```
var a = ($(this).parent()).parent();
var form = $(a+" #modal-form-tag form");
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, why not using `$("#modal-form-tag form")`?

Comment: I am using them but because of code structure they are randomly generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDs are required to be unique, so just `$("#modal-form-tag form")` should be enough.

If you meant to use classes to allow for multiple elements with that identifier, try:

```
$(this.parentNode.parentNode).find(".modal-form-tag form")
```

Note that the above uses some [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) to avoid the extra function calls.

To expand further, if your container has some distinctive feature, like a class name (for this example, I'll assume `class="somecontainer"`), you can do this:

```
$(this).parent(".somecontainer").find(".modal-form-tag form")
```

This will eliminate the guesswork involved in chaining `parent` calls.

Answer (score 0):

`a.find('#modal-form-tag form')` ?